# log4j No appenders could be found for logger even if it has been defined

Tags: log4j

#### My Log4j.xml file ( log4j 1.2.15)

```
<appender name="Append1" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"> 
   <param name="File" value="tomcat/log.out"/>
   <param name="Append" value="true"/> 
   <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>
   </layout>
</appender>
```

#### logger level :

```
<logger name="xx.yy.zzzz.Controller" additivity="false">
     <level value="DEBUG"/>
     <appender-ref ref="Append1"/>
</logger>
```

#### Log in catalina file :

```
  log4j: Setting property [file] to [/log.out].
  log4j: Setting property [append] to [true].
  log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [DEBUG].
  log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
  log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n].
  log4j: setFile called: log.out, true
  log4j: setFile ended
  log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
  log4j: Setting [xx.yy.zzzz.Controller] additivity to [false].
  log4j: Level value for xx.yy.zzzz.Controller is [DEBUG].
  log4j: **xx.yy.zzzz.Controller level set to DEBUG**
  log4j: Adding appender named [Append1] to category [xx.yy.zzzz.Controller].
```

We have this warning message and we do not have the traces

```
  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (xx.yy.zzzz.Controller).
  log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properl
```

y.

the java Class :

```
 public final class Controller {
  private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class);

     public method1(){
        LOGGER.debug("test")
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've just misspelled the case of the logger's name
try

```
<logger name="xx.yy.zzzz.Controller" additivity="false">
 ...
</logger>
```

"Controller" is Uppercase

Comment: Thx ,  it's just a bad copy paste in my log4xml  it's correct with UperCase <logger name="xx.yy.zzzz.Controller" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Append1"/>
</logger> And stil not work

Comment: Sorry for the silly question: do you have also an appender named Append1 in your log4j.xml file ?